# adb bugreport: Is there a way to reset the log?

Tags: android, adb

Hey, I'm new to Android/ADB

I've been asked to dump an adb bugreport log by someone.  I managed to do this, but the report was 640k and had a ton of crash dumps for various apps that I was playing with.  I'm trying to present just the information for the app we're interested in.

Is there a way to reset the log so that I don't have all this other cruft?

thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can clear old logs that are available while starting your application by calling `adb logcat -c` from shell prompt. It should clear any old logs on the buffer and the logs getting printed thereafter should be from your application(at least a majority of them).

Comment: Beware because although this answer might have been true in the past it's no longer valid (at least for my device). Currently bugreport stores logs from couple days and yes if you clear logs with `adb logcat -c` you will not see those logs when doing `adb logcat`, however they will still be in bugreport!

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to clean up old battery collection data before making bug report. Otherwise the output will be bigger.

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats --reset
adb shell bugreport > Bugreport_File_Name.txt
```